# Suspend Ubuntu after 10 minutes but keep awake for certain period

Tags: 14.04, suspend, schedule

I would like to have my Ubuntu pc suspend after 10 minutes inactivity but it must switch on and remain on from midnight to 6:05 am. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `System->Controll Center->Power Management Preferences` and choose `Put computer to sleep when inactive` to 10 minutes.

You can make wake up your computer automatically with `rtcwake` comand.
Have a look here:

```
http://www.howtogeek.com/121241/how-to-make-your-linux-pc-wake-from-sleep-automatically/
```

You also set the the timer (firstly run `sudo su -`) in `/etc/crontab` to be run each day.

```
0 0 * * * rtcwake -m mem -l -t $(date +%s -d ‘tomorrow 00:00’)
5 6 * * * echo mem > /sys/power/state`
```

Sorry for the late replay, I had a busy day yesterday.